# Python replace dictionary value with its extension

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary

How to replace dictionary value with its extension using python? i.e. replace "Eth" with "Ethernet"?

```
{'Po1': ['Eth1/2', 'Eth1/3', 'Eth2/3', 'Eth3/3'], 'Po2': ['Eth2/2', 'Eth2/5'], 'Po201': ['Eth1/1']}
```

Output:

```
{'Po1': ['Ethernet1/2', 'Ethernet1/3', 'Ethernet2/3', 'Ethernet3/3'], 'Po2': ['Ethernet2/2', 'Ethernet2/5'], 'Po201': ['Ethernet1/1']}
```

Comment: Iterate over the strings given in the lists contained in your dict. For each string, call `replace()`.

Comment: Thanks. can you give an example please.

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {'Po1': ['Eth1/2', 'Eth1/3', 'Eth2/3', 'Eth3/3'], 'Po2': ['Eth2/2', 'Eth2/5'], 'Po201': ['Eth1/1']}


out = {}
for key, value in d.items():
    l = []
    for string in value:
        l.append(string.replace('Eth', 'Ethernet'))
    out[key] = l
print(out)


# the above can be re-written using comprehensions
out = {}
for key, value in d.items():
    out[key] = [string.replace('Eth', 'Ethernet') for string in value]
print(out)


# the above can be re-written using nested comprehensions
out = {k: [s.replace('Eth', 'Ethernet') for s in v] for k, v in d.items()}
print(out)
```

Printing:

```
{'Po1': ['Ethernet1/2', 'Ethernet1/3', 'Ethernet2/3', 'Ethernet3/3'], 'Po2': ['Ethernet2/2', 'Ethernet2/5'], 'Po201': ['Ethernet1/1']}
{'Po1': ['Ethernet1/2', 'Ethernet1/3', 'Ethernet2/3', 'Ethernet3/3'], 'Po2': ['Ethernet2/2', 'Ethernet2/5'], 'Po201': ['Ethernet1/1']}
{'Po1': ['Ethernet1/2', 'Ethernet1/3', 'Ethernet2/3', 'Ethernet3/3'], 'Po2': ['Ethernet2/2', 'Ethernet2/5'], 'Po201': ['Ethernet1/1']}
```

Answer (score 0):

The strings can be modified in-place in the lists.  Iterate over the dictionary values, then the lists, then reassign the strings in each list location.  If you are unfamiliar with `enumerate`, it returns the index and value of each element of an iterable.

```py
>>> d = {'Po1': ['Eth1/2', 'Eth1/3', 'Eth2/3', 'Eth3/3'], 'Po2': ['Eth2/2', 'Eth2/5'], 'Po201': ['Eth1/1']}
>>> for v in d.values():
...     for i,s in enumerate(v):
...         v[i] = s.replace('Eth','Ethernet')
...         
>>> d
{'Po1': ['Ethernet1/2', 'Ethernet1/3', 'Ethernet2/3', 'Ethernet3/3'], 'Po2': ['Ethernet2/2', 'Ethernet2/5'], 'Po201': ['Ethernet1/1']}
```